# Wait for spotify app api search to finish [close]

Tags: javascript, spotify

**UPDATE:** New preview API provides an easy solution for this!

Ok I'm having an issue with the new Spotify preview api 1.x. Moreover it is a general javascript/jquery ajax problem.

I have a function that gets a json array from my server backend. The array represents some recommendations that consist of a music track (name, artist). When it is finished I want to search for those tracks via the spotify api.

```
 $.when(getCurrentRecommendationList()).done(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            matchRecommendations(result, showTracksList);
        });
```

So far so good. My match Recommendations function looks something like this:

```
var matchedTracks = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var searchTerm = result[i].song.artist + " " + result[i].song.name;
    var track;

    // Search with SPOTIFY API
    require([ '$api/search#Search' ], function(Search) {
        var search = Search.search(searchTerm);
        search.tracks.snapshot(0, 1).done(function(snapshot) {
        track = snapshot.get(0);
            if (track) {
                var rec = new Recommendation(result[i].id, track);
                matchedTracks.push(rec);
            }
        });
    });
}
return matchedTracks;
```

Don't worry about the searching all works fine. The Problem is that the searching takes some time and my matchedTracks is returned before the search is finished.

I think jquery's deferred will be the solution but as I'm new to javascript and jquery I couldn't really get them to work the way I wanted to, mainly because the loop was giving me troubles ^^.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: You said your using ajax, are you using that to connect to their api? if so where is the ajax call.

Comment: ajax call is in the first code block "getCurrentRecommendationList()" but that works fine. The Spotify search itself seems to be async. wich is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Javascript wants to be asynchronous, so don't return the tracks from the method, use a finished callback.

```
matchRecommendations(result, showTracksList, function(matchedTracks) {
    console.log("tracks finished", matchedTracks);
});



function matchRecommendations(result, showTracksList, matchedTracksCallback) {
    var matchedTracks = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var searchTerm = result[i].song.artist + " " + result[i].song.name;
        var track;

        // Search with SPOTIFY API
        require([ '$api/search#Search' ], function(Search) {
            var search = Search.search(searchTerm);
            search.tracks.snapshot(0, 1).done(function(snapshot) {
            track = snapshot.get(0);
                if (track) {
                    var rec = new Recommendation(result[i].id, track);
                    matchedTracks.push(rec);
                }
            });

            // Call the callback after all tracks are added
            matchedTracksCallback(matchedTracks);
        });
    }

    // don't return anything here
    // return matchedTracks;
}
```

I'm not familiar with the spotify api to know when to call the callback, though...

Comment: As I understand this would work if it was just one search and no loop. Because I need all the tracks in the matchedTracks array before calling the callback function :/